# How do I release memory in swiftui after an image is shown?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uiimage

I have an image as a background, and when I click on the button, it displays the following image based on where the counter is on the array. Each time the counter goes up, the new image is set as the background, and the memory use increases. My images are in my assets folder, and their sizes are 512 x 384 pixels. They are SVG images. I would like when I change to another image, the previous one's memory disappears. Currently, as I change images, the memory use increases by about 4 MB.  So, if I have four images, the memory goes to 16 MB, for example. I would like that as I change to another image, it just stays at four or whatever space my current image takes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var listOfImages: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
    @State var counter = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                
                counter += 1
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Next Image")
            })
        }
        .background(Image(listOfImages[counter]))
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I have tried my app with about 20 images, and the memory keeps on going up. I have seen other posts that say that at some point, it either automatically releases some of the memory or the app crashes. I would like to know if it is possible to keep a steady memory use and if it is, how? My images are drawings.

Answer (score -1):

You don't manage memory in swiftui, it's handled automatically. You can use views, which loads and unloads images (or combined views) on demand. These are named with Lazy in the name, like LazyVStack, LazyHStack, LazyVGrid etc.

You can also check following link: [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init#1674004)

Check "Special considerations" - it recommends to use UIImage instead of Image

Comment: The page you linked doesn't discuss Image. UIImage is something you can initialize an Image with; not something that can replace Image.

Comment: It's saying: "If you intend to display an image only once and don't want it added to the system’s cache, create it using the imageWithContentsOfFile: method instead. Keeping single-use images out of the system image cache can potentially improve the memory use characteristics of your app." I understand it in the way that it's important how you initialize the image. So if you use Image(uiimage: ) instead of Image(from:) it is different.

Comment: Yes, but in both cases you use Image. In neither case do you use "UIImage instead of Image." That's my only point; as worded it confuses future searchers who will read this as saying they should replace Image with UIImage "for performance" and that won't work. Giving an example of what you're describing, and how it would be implemented in the proposed code, would make this a much stronger answer. Actually checking that it helps would make this an excellent answer.